# Swipe Gesture not working in React Navigation v6 in IOS build

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation-v6

I am using Expo SDK 43 and React Navigation v6 for my react native app. I have used React Drawer Navigation in my app navigation. In the development mode inside expo, drawer open and close functions are working perfectly along with Swipe right gesture. When I swipe right at the edge of the app view the Drawer Panel opens perfectly. But when I am building the app using EAS build to submit it to the app store, in the built version the Swipe Gesture is not working at all. The open/close function on a button click is working fine but Swipe gesture is not responding.

```
const StudentNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <DashboardDrawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        gestureEnabled: true,
        swipeEnabled: true,
        drawerType: "slide",
        swipeEdgeWidth: 100,
        swipeMinDistance: 100,
      }}
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
    >
```

I increased the `swipeEdgeWidth` and `swipeMinDistance` values to see if that has any effect but nothing makes it working in IOS build. In Android build everything is working fine. What am I missing here? Is it a bug in expo SDK or anything else?

Here is my package.json configuration:

```
{
  "name": "----------",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/lato": "^0.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "expo": "~43.0.2",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.2.1",
    "expo-application": "~4.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~10.1.3",
    "expo-camera": "~12.0.3",
    "expo-constants": "~12.1.3",
    "expo-device": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-document-picker": "~10.0.3",
    "expo-file-system": "~13.0.3",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.3",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.1.2",
    "expo-image-picker": "~11.0.3",
    "expo-intent-launcher": "~10.0.3",
    "expo-linking": "~2.4.2",
    "expo-network": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.13.3",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.0.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.10.15",
    "lottie-react-native": "4.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-autoheight-webview": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-countup": "^0.0.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-ipify": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Any help will be highly appreciated....

Comment: Any update? Am also seeing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try detachPreviousScreen: false in options of Stack Screen with gestureEnabled: true for ios if screen freezes on back swipe.